# Apisauce interceptor

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, apisauce

Recently i had to rewrite all of my API calls with Apisauce, is amazing but i have very repeating code which looks like this:

```
 const response: ApiResponse<{ result: ReponseType }> = await api.post('endpoint1', reqBody);
    if (!response.ok || !response.data) {
      return getGeneralApiProblem(response);
    }
    return { kind: 'ok', userInfo: response.data.result };
```

```
 const response: ApiResponse<{ result: ReponseType }> = await api.post('endpoint2', reqBody);
    if (!response.ok || !response.data) {
      return getGeneralApiProblem(response);
    }
    return { kind: 'ok', userInfo: response.data.result };
```

```
 const response: ApiResponse<{ result: ReponseType }> = await api.post('endpoint3', reqBody);
    if (!response.ok || !response.data) {
      return getGeneralApiProblem(response);
    }
    return { kind: 'ok', userInfo: response.data.result };
```

How i can extract this part

```
if (!response.ok || !response.data) {
      return getGeneralApiProblem(response);
    }
```

or maybe even this one as well:

```
   return { kind: 'ok', userInfo: response.data.result };
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that changes is the endpoint. How about making another function around `api.post` that takes the endpoint as a parameter?

```
const getAPI = async (endpoint: string) => {
  const response: ApiResponse<{ result: ReponseType }> = await api.post('endpoint1', reqBody);
  if (!response.ok || !response.data) {
    return getGeneralApiProblem(response);
  }
  return { kind: 'ok', userInfo: response.data.result };
}
```

And then your first snippet simplifies to

```
return getAPI('endpoint1');
```

and your second snippet to

```
return getAPI('endpoint2');
```

and so on.

If `reqBody` changes, add it as a parameter too.

Comment: hmm thats good idea, any idea how to handle `ApiResponse<{ result: ReponseType }>` because ReponseType might be dynamic as well

Comment: You could pass `ReponseType` as a generic argument too.

Comment: sorry for dummy question, trying to research it but not sure how to pass it

Comment: Like `const getAPI = async <T extends GenericReponseType>(endpoint: string) => { const response: ApiResponse<{ result: T }> =`, where `GenericReponseType` is the type of all possible `ResponseType` values that could be used. (If there are no restrictions, you can use `unknown`, or leave it off entirely)